# How to modify function so as to return 2 DataFrame depending on values in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have function in Python Pandas like below:

```
def my_func(df, col: str):
    if pd.isna(df[col]):
          return False
```

To use my function I need: `df_resul = my_func(df = my_df, col = "col1")`

And Data Frame like below where col1 is string data type:

```
col1
--------
NaN
ABC
NaN
```

How can I modify my function, so as to as a result have 2 different DataFrames:

1. Where in col1 is NaN
2. Where in col1 is value other than NaN

So to use my function I need: `df_nan, df_not_nan = my_func(df = my_df, col = "col1")`
where df_nan will return df where in col1 is nan and df_not_nan will return df where in col is value other than nan.

df_nan:

```
col1
------
NaN
NaN
```

df_not_nan:

```
col1
-----
ABC
```

How can I modify my function in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `~` fo rinvert mask, here for select non missing values rows:

```
print (my_df)
  col1  a
0  NaN  1
1  ABC  2
2  NaN  3

def my_func(df, col: str):
    m = df[col].isna()
    return df[m], df[~m]
 
df_nan, df_not_nan = my_func(df = my_df, col = "col1")
print (df_nan)
  col1  a
0  NaN  1
2  NaN  3

print (df_not_nan)
  col1  a
1  ABC  2
```

If need test if exist at least one missing value is necesary add [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) for avoid error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

```
def my_func1(df, col: str):
    if pd.isna(df[col]).any():
        return  'exist at least one missing values'
    else:
        return 'no missing values'

 
out = my_func1(df = my_df, col = "col1")
print (out)
exist at least one missing values
```

Comment: Hmmm, you modify my if statement, is it possible to do not modify if? I need to have if in function

Comment: @ratus111 - Yes, I have to do it, because wrong `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Ok, so I am waiting for your modification so as to have my if statement in function, please :)

Comment: @ratus111 - In pandas is not possible use `if` with array, check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas). Only way is create boolean mask and filtering like my answer.

Comment: @ratus111 - added to answer

Comment: I edited my question where I add my ful function to modification not sample, do you know how to modify it to return 2 Data Frames depending on value True / False ?

Comment: @ratus111 - because use `.apply()` not possible.

Comment: did you see modification  of my question? I updated the full version of fucntion which I try to modify to have as a result 2 different DF

Comment: @ratus111 - Not possible, because `test_df["val"].apply(check_val)` processing by loop byu each value of column `val`